# WPF ItemsControl get the XAML elements programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ItemsControl filled with a ModelView and this XAML markup:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0, 0, 0, 5">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="5, 2, 0, 0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

I want to get the TextBlock element programmatically so I can change it's style after validating the data, how can I do this?

Comment: Why do you have to do it programmatically? You could change the style right in the template, that is if I'm understanding your question correctly.

Comment: @ChrisW. It's a bit more than just the style, I have a TextBlock and a Button, when the user clicks the button, I switch the Block for a Box, allow him to edit and close. I need to "reset" this event so I need to get the elements in there somehow.

Comment: Put your Block and Box in there, make the non-default one Collapsed Visibility, a quick ChangePropertyAction on an event trigger on your Button/Toggle can swap them out, it's no big deal. Though maybe I'm bias since I'm a big xaml fan. ;)

Comment: The problem is a bit different, that's what it does currently, but after the user clicks `Save`, I want to reset the buttons/boxes to their default state (non-editable) except for the fields that failed validation, which will go to Box if it's Block (and change the style).

Answer (score 0):

Add name to items control, for example:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="MyStack" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0, 0, 0, 5">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Margin="5, 2, 0, 0" />
</StackPanel>
```

Add a StackPanel public Property in your CustomControl, for example:

```
public StackPanel ItemsControl {get;set;}
```

And override the OnApplyTemplate of your custom control to:

```
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    ItemsControl = GetTemplateChild("MyStack") as StackPanel;
}
```

And you will be able to access the stackpanel and its children.